# Convert Oracle query "as of timestamp" to LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, oracle

Any knows how to convert this [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/index.html) query into [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) statement or any work around that has same result?

```
select * from TableName as of timestamp to_timestamp('17-Jun-12', 'DD-Mon-yy') where TableName.id = some_Id_input;
```

Comment: The latest ODAC from Oracle (11.2.0.3.0) contains LINQ support, not sure about this exact feature.  Try checking for "flashback" or "flashback query" in your LINQ documentation.

Comment: If LINQ must be "worked around" perhaps it's time to scrap it and just use SQL.